# Error bound on floating point multiplication

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, ieee-754

I'm looking for a formula which bounds the error propagated by a floating point multiplication. I've seen the following stated (but not proved).

If `xa` is a floating point approximation to `x` with bound `ux` ulps, and similarly `ya` is a floating point approximation to `y` with bound `uy` ulps and `p` is the floating point precision then the bound on the correctly rounded product `xa*ya` is `ux + uy + ux*uy/(2^p) + 0.5` ulps.

I have seen the following simpler result proved. If `ya` is an approximation to `y` with bound `uy` ulps then the bound on the correctly rounded product `x*ya` is `uy + 0.5` ulps.

So I guess I'm looking for a proof of the first result, or at least a confirmation that it's correct.

TIA

EDIT

Having taken on board what Mark Dickinson said in the comments below and having reread Florian Loitsch's paper (from where the second formula above comes) it's clear that the ulps in this question are relative to a potentially denormalised result. For instance using the example Mark gave and calculating the product by the non-IEEE method of multiplying the mantissa and dropping the lower 53 bits (but rounding if necessary) we get

```
 x   = 0x1.8000000000000p-1
 y   = 0x1.4000000000000p+0
ya   = 0x1.3fffffffffff6p+0
x*y  = 0x0.f000000000000p+0 (denormalised)
x*ya - 0x0.ffffffffffff8p+8 (denormalised)
```

which is an error of 8 ulp, and within the bounds of the second formula.

Comment: Neither result is true: both neglect the factor-of-two "wobble" incurred in the ulp error when you move from the bottom of one binade to the top of the one below (while keeping the relative error constant). For a counterexample to the simpler result, suppose IEEE 754 binary64 format and semantics, `x = 0.75`, `y = 1.25` and `uy = 10` (say `ya = 1.25 - 10 * 2**-52`). Then `x * ya` is out from the true result `x * y` by 15 ulps. (Rounding mode isn't relevant, because both multiplications are exact.) So I'd be curious to see the "proof" of the second statement.

Comment: The proof is in Florian Loitsch paper 'Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately with Integers', Lemma 3.4. It's a well known paper so I've probably misrepresented what it says.

Comment: @MarkDickinson What do you mean when you say *while keeping the relative error constant*? I believe the formulae I quoted assume that the error bound is relative to the result. So in the example you quote is the error of 15 ulps being measured against `ya` or `x*ya`?

Comment: I meant `15 * ulp(x*ya)` for the result (it wouldn't make sense to be looking at ulps for y, since `x*ya` may have a completely different magnitude). I confess I'm confused by what's going on in that paper. There are statements like "Since, for x⊗y, 1 ulp = 2^(q+ex+ey) ..." (in the proof of Lemma 3.3) that don't seem right, unless there's some unconventional definition of ulp going on - given knowledge of the binade of x and the binade of y, there are *two* possible binades `x*y` might land in, so two possibilities for the ulp of `x*y`. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Ah, I think I see, on a closer reading: for the "diy_fp" type, the multiplication result is *not* necessarily normalised, so I think there's some sleight of hand going on in the definition of ulp (that isn't quite made explicit). So indeed the use of "ulp" in that paper doesn't exactly match the standard usage (or rather, any of the standard uses, since there isn't universal agreement on exactly what ulp means anyway, especially near a radix-power boundary). Here's [some reading](http://www.ens-lyon.fr/LIP/Pub/Rapports/RR/RR2005/RR2005-09.pdf) on the subject.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I've programmed the example you gave with IEEE754 arithmetic, and I agree the error is 15 ulp. I think I'm going to have to run the same example through the arithemetic used by the paper and see what happens. The proof made sense to me when I read it BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the link as well.

Comment: In Florian’s Lemma 3.4, *x* is an exact number. It is represented in floating-point but is considered only for that value it exactly results. In contrast, *ỹ* is a floating-point number that is an approximation of some real *y*, with an error less than uy. In your question, you introduce a ux that is not in the lemma.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes I understand that. It's the point of the question, I want to confirm the given formula when both x and y are inexact.

Comment: @john: You said you have “seen the following stated.” But it is not stated in the source you cited, Florian Loitsch’s paper, since the statement in the question differs from that in the paper. Where did you see it stated?

Comment: @EricPostpischil In a source code comment in the google double conversion library. See [here](https://github.com/google/double-conversion/blob/master/double-conversion/strtod.cc), line 322

Comment: When you say "with bound `ux` ulps", you need to say whether you consider ulp(`xa`) or ulp(`x`), as the real value `x` and its approximation `xa` may not be in the same binade, thus have different ulp values. Also, I suppose that you assume that `ux` is small enough for the given precision p so that you will not cross several binades for the input values, but also anywhere in the error analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the ulps are relative to the approximations (I believe that the other case is more difficult, and less useful anyway), [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/)'s [`doc/algorithms.tex`](https://gforge.inria.fr/scm/viewvc.php/mpfr/trunk/doc/algorithms.tex?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain) document has a proof of the following result, here rewritten to follow your notation and simplified for a unique precision p.

If you have

- |xa − x| ≤ ux · ulp(xa)
- |ya − y| ≤ uy · ulp(ya)

then the error for the product rounded to nearest is bounded by [(2 + 2<sup>1−p</sup>)(ux + uy) + 1/2] · ulp(`xa*ya`).

This is generally larger than the bound you gave, with about a factor 2. However, the validity of the bound you gave needs to be confirmed. Finding tight error bounds is difficult in general, as one can easily lose a factor 2 (wobble) as the ulp changes by a factor 2 at powers of 2, and this can either be due to a suboptimal proof or a real loss of accuracy in corner cases.